# How to generate PDF reports in SonarQube 6.4?

Tags: java, sonarqube, pdf-generation

I used to use SonarQube 3.7.4 where I was able to generate PDF reports when I have been using JDK 1.7.

I upgraded to JDK 1.8 which is not supported in SonarQube 3.7.4. Therefore I upgraded to SonarQube 6.4, but the PDF plugin is not available anymore and I am not able to generate reports. I also tried many available plugins, but they do not work with SonarQube 6.4.

How can I generate PDF reports in SonarQube 6.4?

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by "not working." What goes wrong when you try to use them?

Comment: "not working" means when i place PDF report plugin jar in the plugins folder the sonar fails to start, but without the plugin jar soar is running fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no PDF reporting available for 6.4.

If you really have to have reporting outside of SonarQube itself, then you'll need to look at the [web services](https://sonarcloud.io/web_api) to pull data.